# How to show ManyToMany model in template?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my models:

```
class Champion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.role

class Matchup(models.Model):
    champ1 = models.ManyToManyField(Champion, related_name='champ1')
    champ2 = models.ManyToManyField(Champion, related_name='champ2')
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
    minute = models.IntegerField()
    gold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
```

Here is views:

```
def adc(request):
    matchups = Matchup.objects.filter(champ1__role = "ADC")
    return render(request, 'ADC.html', { 'matchups' : matchups})
```

I am trying to show champ1 name. However, this doesn't help:

```
{%for i in matchups.champ1.all%}
{{i.name}} 
{%endfor%}
```

What to do?

Comment: What is happening when you run your code? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: do you want to show all the matchups for a single champ?

Comment: I want to show  the name of all ADC matchups first champ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matchups is a collection

```
{% for m in matchups.all %}
  {% for i in m.champ1.all %}
    {{ i.name }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```